# Isomorphism of algebras depending on the field

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras

Let $X$ be a finite set of primes (where 0 is also a prime, but 1 is not!).
Are there two quiver algebra $A_1=KQ/I_1$ and $A_2=KQ/I_2$ such that the coefficeints of the generators of the ideals $I_1$ and $I_2$ contain only field elements 1 and -1 and are admissible for any field $K$ and we have $KQ/I_1 \cong KQ/I_2$ iff $K$ has characteristic $p \notin X$?

I am only aware of such an example for $X= \{2 \}$, namely the penny farthing algebras. Are there any other examples?

Is it true that in case $A_1$ and $A_2$ are representation-finite for any $K$, such a thing can only happen for $X= \{ 2\}$?

Here is the example of the penny-farthing algebras:

Let $Q$ be the quiver with 2 vertices 1 and 2 and arrows $a$ from 2 to 1 and $b$ from 1 to 2 and $y$ from 2 to 2. Let $I_1=\langle ab-y^2,ba\rangle$ and $I_2=\langle ab-y^2,y^4,ba-bya\rangle$.

> Question: What is the best way to show that $KQ/I_2$ is isomorphic to $KQ/I_2$ iff $K$ has characteristic different from 2?

Of course it is possible with brute froce, but maybe there is an elementary nice way (I am not aware of an elementary invariant to distinguish those two algebras in characteristic 2).

This is exercise 8 in chapter III the Representation theory of Artin algebras book by Auslander, Reiten and Smalo.

Comment: Something's wrong here. The only ideal containing $\pm 1$ is $A$ itself. Do you mean "$I_i$ is generated by polynomials whose coefficients are either $\pm 1$ or $0$" or something along those lines?

Comment: @JohannesHahn Yes, thanks.